# scriptsharp reference web service / strongly type to results model

Tags: .net, script#

With scriptsharp (script#) is it possible to get strong typing when calling a service defined in my web app?  The only way I can see is to:
1 - use linked / shared files to shadow copy my results classes / domain models across into my script# lib
2 - replicate my model across in the script# lib and use automapper to validate?
3 - use some .tt to code gen?

also, even if I can do this, how do I get around the auto camel-casing script# does, when my service result (asmx) wont do this?  (so my JSON response will comback as UserMessage, script# will have changed that to userMessage)

basically, what I am looking to use script# to achieve is better compile time support against our domain model when calling and processing services in javascript, so something like this:

Scriptlet

```
public static class MyScriptlet
{  
    public static void Main()
    {
        MyService.Service1("hello", ProcessResponse);
    }  
    public static void ProcessResponse(MyService.Service1ResponseData resp)
    {  
        jQuery.Select('#Message').Text(resp.UserMessage);  
        jQuery.Select('#Detail').Text(resp.UserDetail);  
    }
}
```

Service (in our web app)

```
public class MyService
{
    public class Service1ResponseData
    {
        public string UserMessage {get;set;}
        public string UserDetail {get;set;}
    }
    public Service1ResponseData Service1(string user)
    {
        return new Service1ResponseData() { UserMessage:"hi",UserDetail:"some text" };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Number 2 works, and you only have to add [PreserveCase] attributes to get around the camel casing.

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

[Imported]
[IgnoreNamespace]
public sealed class Service1ResponseData
{

    [PreserveCase]
    public string UserMessage;

    [PreserveCase]
    public string UserDetail;
}
```